How to clean refrigerator water dispensing system when refrigerator water shutoff cannot be accessed?
I would like to clean the water dispensing system in my Bosch refrigerator. I found these guidelines suggesting that I locate the water tube going into the refrigerator and flush the system with vinegar: https://www.bosch-home.co.uk/customer-service/get-support/fridge-freezers/cleaning-water-dispenser
However, the water shutoff valve and water tube for my refrigerator is behind the refrigerator itself. It is a built in refrigerator and thus very difficult to move. Is there another way to clean the water dispensing system that does not require me to access the tube behind the refrigerator?

If Bosch requires it, you could shut off the main water supply and flush toilets to bleed water pressure, However, if not required, and it isn't broken, don't bother.

how often do you clean your kitchen sink tap and water lines?

So, the shutoff valve is located where it's completely useless if you need to shut it off. Well planned, installers.

There SHOULD be a valve at the other end of that supply tube, where it joins your plumbing. You could try disconnecting and injecting the vinegar (under pressure?) there, with someone else to operate the dispenser.
But... Why do you think you need to clean it? Mineral deposits? Or just "someone suggested it might be a good thing to do?" If the dispenser is still working properly, this seems unnecessary.

Agree with this answer, but can say that sometimes valves/connections are located underneath the appliance (basement/crawlspace).

@keshlam Thanks for your response. I want to clean it because we found that the water dispenser was dispensing water with a pieces of clear/yellowish film in it. We changed the water filter and ran about 3 gallons of water through it, but the film pieces were still showing up. My intuition is that the film is in the water tube, but I could be wrong. I'm happy to try something else (instead of flushing the tube with vinegar) if you think there is a better fix for this issue.

If the pieces if whatever are showing up despite a filter, either the filter is being bypassed or they are originating inside the fridge. I'd look for reports from other owners who have dealt with this...
